# Bind multiselect selections to list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model like so:

```
public class ListingPlanEditorViewModel
{
    public ListingPlan Plan { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Directory> SiteDirectories { get; set; }
}
```

One property is an object of type ListingPlan here:

```
public class ListingPlan
{
    public int? ListingPlanID { get; set; }
    public int DescriptionLinesCount { get; set; }
    public List<Directory> Directories { get; set; }
}
```

The object Directory looks like this:

```
public class Directory
{
    public int DirectoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller that returns a ListingPlanEditorViewModel to the view:

```
   public ActionResult ConfigurePlan(int? listingIdentifier)
    {
        ListingPlan plan = new ListingPlan()
        {
            DescriptionLinesCount = 10,
            Directories = new List<Directory>()
            {
                new Directory()
                {
                    DirectoryID = 3
                },
                new Directory()
                {
                    DirectoryID = 4
                }
            }
        };
        ListingPlanEditorViewModel model = new ListingPlanEditorViewModel()
        {
            Plan = plan,//_listingRepository.GetListingPlan(listingIdentifier, null),
            SiteDirectories = _database.GetDirectories()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

I would like to create a multiselect box that will bind the selected values back to the Plan property in the ListingPlanEditorViewModel, setting the DirectoryID property for each selection. So after binding I should have a List of Directory objects. All with their DirectoryID's set.

I'm having some trouble doing this. I can create the multiselectbox with the correct select options in it, but I am unable to retrieve them in my post action which looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfigurePlan", "ListingPlan"))
{
    <div class="form-body">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Plan.Directories, new MultiSelectList(Model.SiteDirectories, "DirectoryID", "Name"))
</div>

<button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an `[]` or `List` of `IDs` in the ViewModel that will store selected values.

```
public class ListingPlanEditorViewModel
{
    public ListingPlan Plan { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Directory> SiteDirectories { get; set; }
    public int[] DirectoryIDs {get;set;}
}
```

The View will change according. The Directories selected will be stored in `DirectoryIDs`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfigurePlan", "ListingPlan"))
{
    <div class="form-body">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.DirectoryIDs, new MultiSelectList(Model.SiteDirectories, "DirectoryID", "Name"))
    </div>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

Now on `POST` Action you can query the database and get the `Directories` that was selected by user.

**Note:** You can't just get the *full objects* because the `ListBoxFor` will generate a `<select multiple ... > ... </select>` tag won't know how to bind to your object.

Comment: I think you mean `public int[] DirectoryIDs {get;set;}` :)

Comment: @Stephen-Muecke You have hawk eyes sir, I was talking about an array involved but I forgot to add it.